# Combine these two regex patterns

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

I have two regex values that I have been trying to combine into a single statement however it is not working properly. I need to be able to display lines that have comments in them or start with a blank space and then have the comments.

ie.

```
/* comment 

      /* comment

sed -n "/\(^[/*]\).*\([*/]$\)/ p" testfile

sed -n "/^\s/ p" testfile
```

I have been trying using the | statement however it is not working.

Is it possible to merge them into one or do I need to run them separately.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find comments in C programs or something else? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Include the cases that will be hard to get right, eg `/*` appearing in a string.

Answer (score 1):

this should cover both cases

```
/^\s*\/\*.*/
```

Comment: Or `/^\s*\/\*/`, the `.*` at the end will always match anyway.

Comment: yes but if used for replacement you have to capture the rest as well.

Comment: Absolutely - my comment only applies to usage in an address.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
/^[ ]*(\/\*.*)$/
```

---

The regex above will match any lines with comments, that can start with spaces, and capture the line to a group. Check the [**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wQ9sT8/2)

---

**Regex Explanation**

```
/^[ ]*(\/\*.*)$/

    ^ assert position at start of a line
    [ ]* match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
         the literal character  
    1st Capturing group (\/\*.*)
        \/ matches the character / literally
        \* matches the character * literally
        .* matches any character (except newline)
            Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    $ assert position at end of a line
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers illustrate, it is often possible to find a regular expression general enough to match everything your original expressions matched. In fact, this is always possible, since you can always combine two expressions like this:

```
(regex_1|regex_2|...|regex_n)
```

(Depending on the dialect you use, you might have to use backslashes.) However, a `sed` program may consist of several statements, so your example could be simply rewritten as:

```
sed -n "/\(^[/*]\).*\([*/]$\)/p /^\s/p" testfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep:

```
grep "^ */\*" testfile
```

^=start of line
First * is repeating the space 0 or more times
Second star is escaped, so that is a real one.